# Custom ListView from inside HubAppSection -- Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am currently building a Windows Phone Applicaation, based off of the HubAppTemplate.
The template comes with a sample .JSON data source that it uses to populate the data of each HubSection. However, I want to use a non JSON type of data as the basis of my code. Inside my C# code, I need to make a function call to my backend to get the type of data I want out of it.

I can put this data inside of my own custom list (on the C# side), but how can I make that list act as the data source for my HubSection? Any old listview/list box works perfectly. Basically, I need help wiring the C# to the XAML -- the main issue is that I cannot access my listView inside of the datatemplate by name.

Can anyone give me some pointers to get going in the right direction?

Here is some reference code to show you what I am talking about:

```
<HubSection x:Uid="Clubs" Header="Clubs" DataContext="{Binding Groups}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView Name="ClubsList"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                    ItemClick="GroupSection_ItemClick"
                    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,27.5">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

The above XAML is basically pulled straight from the hubapp template. I want to be able to use my own itemssource inside of that ListView that is generated from my C# code -- however, I cannot figure out how this ItemsSource works. I also cannot access my listview by name (ClubsList).

Here is the initialization code going on up top (wasn't sure if it was important to post this or not):

```
<Page
x:Class="HubAppTemplate.HubPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:HubAppTemplate"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:HubAppTemplate.Data"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"
mc:Ignorable="d"> 

<Page.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="HubSectionHeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,-9.5" Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- Grid-appropriate item template as seen in section 2 -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Standard200x180TileItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,9.5,9.5" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" Height="138.5" Width="138.5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="9.5,0,0,6.5" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="StandardTripleLineItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,9.5,0,0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" Height="79" Width="79"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="14.5,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource PhoneMidBrush}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="StandardDoubleLineItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,9.5,0,0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" Height="79" Width="79"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="14.5,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Hub x:Name="Hub" x:Uid="Hub" Header="Club Alert" Background="{ThemeResource HubBackgroundImageBrush}">
```

It is pulling from the JSON backend, but I want to just use my own custom listview for each section. Deleting the DataSource and data template headers gives me errors, however.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

--A total newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HubSection` elements require their contents to be populated via a template, so you can't just remove the `<DataTemplate>` tags, unfortunately. However, there is a simple way to accomplish what you are trying to do, if I understand you correctly.

If you're starting with the default Hub template, you should have this function in your HubPage.xaml.cs file

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
            var sampleDataGroups = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupsAsync();
            this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = sampleDataGroups;

            MainViewModel viewModel = DataContext as MainViewModel;
            if (!viewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            {
                viewModel.Load();
            }
        }
```

`this.DefaultViewModel` is just a Dictionary, and they have loaded the sample JSON into a variable and stored this in the `["Groups"]` key of the dictionary. Since the Page's `DataContext` is being bound to `{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`, the HubSection's DataContext is being bound to `{Binding Groups}`, and the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` in each DataTemplate is being bound to `{Binding}`, each element of the loaded JSON is being used to fill the items of the `ListView`.

A simple solution would be to assign `this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"]` to the C# List you are creating from the data you load from your back end.

Something like this:

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
            {
                // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
                var myData = await GetListOfThingsFromBackend();
                this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = myData;

                MainViewModel viewModel = DataContext as MainViewModel;
                if (!viewModel.IsDataLoaded)
                {
                    viewModel.Load();
                }
            }
```

A better approach would probably be to separate out all ViewModel functionality to it's own class that is better suited to your needs, and then adjust the various DataContext properties throughout the XAML, but that would likely take more time. I can elaborate if needed, but the simple solution is probably enough for now.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't have enough karma to upvote you, but I really appreciate the effort.